# How do I bind directly to a property of a member?

Tags: xamarin.forms

If a class has an member of type `NotifyPropertyChangedBase`, how can an instance bind directly to a property change?

In other words, I don't want to bind to a property on a data binding context, I want to directly listen for changes to a property of a member.

So this is the property that I want to listen to...

```
public class MyClass : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get => myProperty;
        set
        {
            if (myProperty != value)
            {
                myProperty = value;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
```

Then another class has an instance of this type...

```
public class MyClass2
{
   MyClass myClass;
```

`MyClass2` is not a visual element. How does it listen for changes to the property in `myClass`?

Comment: subscribe to the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you please add some sample code

Comment: @UmairM I've updated the question.

Comment: @Jason lol, yes that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would just subscribe to MyClass' PropertyChanged event